# How to get the GROUP BY and SUM of categories and print in a single line in Laravel MongoDB

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm newbie in MongoDB and I'm really struggling to get the expected output. I have a set of records in collection, let's say:

`{"_id": "id", "category": "Category A", "price": 100, "created_at": "2022-02-01 01:05:00"},`
`{"_id": "id", "category": "Category B", "price": 200, "created_at": "2022-02-01 01:10:00"},`
`{"_id": "id", "category": "Category B", "price": 150, "created_at": "2022-02-01 01:20:00"}`

I want to group these by hour (created_at), and by categories, and get the sum of each category's price in a single line like this:

`{"_id": "id", "Category A Total Price": 100, "Category B Total Price": 350, "created_at": "2022-02-01 01:00:00"}`

Does this problem needs different query for each category and then merge? Or any solution you can share.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {}
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        category: "$category",
        created_at: {
          $dateTrunc: {
            date: { "$toDate": "$created_at" },
            unit: "day"
          }
        }
      },
      "total": { "$sum": "$price" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.created_at",
      "obj": {
        "$push": {
          k: { "$concat": [ "$_id.category", " Total Price" ] },
          v: "$total"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $mergeObjects: [
        { "$arrayToObject": "$obj" },
        { created_at: "$_id" }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aknpkGapa7d)